# How to make URL to the same location as a form in Django?

Tags: django

I have some Django app, which has a geolocation form, which I would like to understand how it works as an example.

I can fill form with from and to addresses and when I press `Go` button it will open the following url

```
http://mysite/?route_from=32.71568%2C-117.16171&route_to=34.05361%2C-118.2455&auto_update=false
```

and it shows the route between cities.

The form is encoded with

```
{% block content %}
    {% with action=using_next|default:"home" %}
        <form method="get" action="{% url 'ui:'|add:action %}">
...
                        <input name="auto_update" type="hidden" value="false"/>
                        <button type="submit">{% if using_next %}Go!{% else %}Save{% endif %}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    {% endwith %}
```

I was wishing to make static URL to instantly open the same route and added inside with

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="box">
                <div id="predefined_01">
                    Example 01: <a href="{% url 'ui:'|add:action  route_from='32.71568,-117.16171' route_to='34.05361,-118.2455' auto_update='false' %}">San Diego - Lon Angeles</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was thinking it will fill the same arguments as a form and navigate to the same place.

Unfortunately, it swears upon render:

> NoReverseMatch at /settings/
> Reverse for 'tracker' with keyword
> arguments '{'route_from': '32.71568,-117.16171', 'route_to':
> '34.05361,-118.2455', 'auto_update': 'false'}' not found. 1 pattern(s)
> tried: ['$']

`settings` is a current page.

What I did wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameters are not keyword arguments and are not part of the URL resolving.

`/path` and `/path?optional=1` are the same url `/path`.

To create the correct url with correct query parameters use:

```
<a href="{% url 'ui:'|add:action %}?route_from={{'32.71568,-117.16171'|urlencode}}&amp;route_to={{'34.05361,-118.2455'|urlencode}}&amp;auto_update=false">link</a>
```